# How can one verify messages sent to self are delivered when testing Akka actors?

Tags: scala, testing, akka

I have an Actor that is similar to the following Actor in function.

```
case class SupervisingActor() extends Actor {

    protected val processRouter = //round robin router to remote workers
    override def receive = {
        case StartProcessing => { //sent from main or someplace else
            for (some specified number of process actions ){
                processRouter ! WorkInstructions
            }
        }
        case ProcessResults(resultDetails) => {  //sent from the remote workers when they complete their work
            //do something with the results
            if(all of the results have been received){
                //*********************
                self ! EndProcess  //This is the line in question
                //*********************
            }
        }
        case EndProcess {
            //do some reporting
            //shutdown the ActorSystem
        }
    }
}
```

}

How can I verify the EndProcess message is sent to self in tests?

I'm using scalatest 2.0.M4, Akka 2.0.3 and Scala 1.9.2.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

An actor sending to itself is very much an intimiate detail of how that actor performs a certain function, hence I would rather test the effect of that message than whether or not that message has been delivered. I’d argue that sending to self is the same as having a private helper method on an object in classical OOP: you also do not test whether that one is invoked, you test whether the right thing happened in the end.

As a side note: you could implement your own message queue type (see https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/mailboxes.html#creating-your-own-mailbox-type) and have that allow the inspection or tracing of message sends. The beauty of this approach is that it can be inserted purely by configuration into the actor under test.

Comment: I wound up testing the effects of the message as you described although not for the reasons you present.  I did it because I could figure out no other way to test the message.  I agree with your argument however.  Donald's answer suggests a good low level testing tool.  Thanks.

Comment: As I understand, the same reasoning applies to child actors created by the actor under test? Like, we shouldn't test the message flow between those actors because they can also be viewed as internal implementation, right?

Comment: I had a similar problem and found out how to solve it with a message queue/mailbox. In this answer I show how it can be implemented: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51401851/302793

Answer (score 0):

In the past, I have overridden the implementation for `!` so that I could add debug/logging. Just call super.! when you're done, and be extra careful not to do anything that would throw an exception.

Comment: This is an excellent idea (and one I should have thought of).  However, after considering Roland's argument for a bit, I think overriding ! is a tool to be used if one needs to examine why the tests Roland describes are failing.  Thank you for the answer.

Comment: doesnt seem to work as self is final val in latest akka.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with an FSM actor. I tried setting up a custom mailbox as per the accepted answer but a few minutes didn't get it working. I also attempted to override the tell operator as per another  answer but that was not possible as self is a final val. Eventually I just replaced:

```
 self ! whatever
```

with:

```
 sendToSelf(whatever)
```

and added that method into the actor as:

```
// test can override this
protected def sendToSelf(msg: Any) {
  self ! msg
}
```

then in the test overrode the method to capture the self sent message and sent it back into the fsm to complete the work:

```
  @transient var sent: Seq[Any] = Seq.empty

  val fsm = TestFSMRef(new MyActor(x,yz) {
    override def sendToSelf(msg: Any) {
      sent = sent :+ msg
    }
  })

  // yes this is clunky but it works
  var wait = 100
  while( sent.isEmpty && wait > 0 ){
    Thread.sleep(10)
    wait = wait - 10
  }

  fsm ! sent.head
```