# Ensure message order in test when mixing futures with actor messages

Tags: scala, testing, akka, actor, akka-testkit

I'm testing an actor that uses an asnychronous future-based API. The actor uses the pipe pattern to send a message to itself when a future completes:

```
import akka.pattern.pipe
// ...

// somewhere in the actor's receive method
futureBasedApi.doSomething().pipeTo(self)
```

In my test I mock the API so I control future completion via promises. However, this is interleaved with other messages sent directly to the actor:

```
myActor ! Message("A")
promiseFromApiCall.success(Message("B"))
myActor ! Message("C")
```

Now I'm wondering how I can guarantee that the actor receives and
processes message B between message A and C in my test because message B is actually sent in another thread, so I can't control the order
in which the actor's mailbox receives the messages.

I thought about several possible solutions:

- sleep after each message for a few milliseconds to make another
  order very unlikely
- wait for the actor to acknowledge each message, although
  acknowledgement is only required for testing
- send message B directly to the actor to simulate completion of the
  future and write a separate test that ensures that the pipe pattern
  is properly used (the test above would not fail if the actor would
  not pipe the result message to itself)

I don't really like either of these options but I tend to use the last
one. Is there another better way I can enforce a certain message order in the tests?

**Clarification:** The question is not how to deal with the fact that messages might be received in random order in production. Controlling the order in the test is essential to make sure that the actor can actually deal with different message orders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading a lot more about akka, I finally found a better solution: Replacing the actor mailbox with one I can observe in the tests. This way I can wait until the actor receives a new message after I complete the promise. Only then the next message is sent. The code for this `TestingMailbox` is given at the end of the post.

**Update:** In Akka Typed this can be achieved very elegantly with a `BehaviorInterceptor`. Just wrap the `Behavior` under test with a custom interceptor that forwards all messages and signals but lets you observe them. 
The mailbox solution for untyped Akka is given below.

---

The actor can be configured like this:

```
actorUnderTest = system.actorOf(Props[MyActor]).withMailbox("testing-mailbox"))
```

I have to make sure the "testing-mailbox" is known by the actor system by providing a configuration:

```
class MyTest extends TestKit(ActorSystem("some name",
    ConfigFactory.parseString("""{ 
        testing-mailbox = {
            mailbox-type = "my.package.TestingMailbox" 
        }
    }"""))) 
    with BeforeAndAfterAll // ... and so on
```

With this being set up, I can change my test like this:

```
myActor ! Message("A")
val nextMessage = TestingMailbox.nextMessage(actorUnderTest)
promiseFromApiCall.success(Message("B"))
Await.ready(nextMessage, 3.seconds)
myActor ! Message("C")
```

With a little helper method, I can even write it like this:

```
myActor ! Message("A")
receiveMessageAfter { promiseFromApiCall.success(Message("B")) }
myActor ! Message("C")
```

And this is my custom mailbox:

```
import akka.actor.{ActorRef, ActorSystem}
import akka.dispatch._
import com.typesafe.config.Config 
import scala.concurrent.{Future, Promise}

object TestingMailbox {

  val promisesByReceiver =
    scala.collection.concurrent.TrieMap[ActorRef, Promise[Any]]()

  class MessageQueue extends UnboundedMailbox.MessageQueue {

    override def enqueue(receiver: ActorRef, handle: Envelope): Unit = {
      super.enqueue(receiver, handle)
      promisesByReceiver.remove(receiver).foreach(_.success(handle.message))
    }

  }

  def nextMessage(receiver: ActorRef): Future[Any] =
    promisesByReceiver.getOrElseUpdate(receiver, Promise[Any]).future

}

class TestingMailbox extends MailboxType
  with ProducesMessageQueue[TestingMailbox.MessageQueue] {

  import TestingMailbox._

  def this(settings: ActorSystem.Settings, config: Config) = this()

  final override def create(owner: Option[ActorRef],
                            system: Option[ActorSystem]) =
      new MessageQueue()

}
```

Answer (score 1):

One idea is to define a flag in your actor that indicates whether the actor has received message B. When the actor receives message C, the actor can [stash](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/actors.html#stash) that message C if the flag is false, then unstash it once the actor receives message B. For example:

```
class MyActor extends Actor with Stash {

  def receiveBlock(seenMsgB: Boolean, seenMsgC: Boolean): Receive = {
    case MakeApiCall =>
      callExternalApi().mapTo[MessageB].pipeTo(self)

    case m: MessageB if seenMsgC => // assume msg C has been stashed
      unstashAll()
      // ...do something with msg B
      become(receiveBlock(true, seenMsgC)) // true, true
    case m: MessageB if !seenMsgC =>
      // ...do something with message B
      become(receiveBlock(true, seenMsgC)) // true, false

    case m: MessageC if seenMsgB =>
      // ...do something with message C
      context.become(receiveBlock(seenMsgB, true)) // true, true
    case m: MessageC if !seenMsgB =>
      stash()
      context.become(receiveBlock(seenMsgB, true)) // false, true

    case ...
  }

  def receive = receiveBlock(false, false)
}
```

Comment: Sorry, my question might have been misleading. It's not about making the actor more robust with regard to different message orders but to produce a certain order in the test to make sure it can handle it. I appended another paragraph to the question to make this clear.

Comment: Can you use the same approach with the stateful actor with stash used as forwarding accumulating proxy for all calls to actor under test?
So just send all messages to this proxy actor, and his role is to ensure that message B will be forwarded only after message A etc.

Comment: @DanilaPolevshikov the problem is that the actor won't know of the proxy when it sends a message to itself when the future completes.

Comment: @jeffrey-chung I finally found a solution and posted it as an answer. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If it is so important to order messages you should use `ask` (`?`) which returns `Future` and chain them even if you dont expect any response from an actor.